# system transaction .net remove exception from session

Tags: asp.net, system, transactions

I am new to asp.net. I am working on an application that is doing system transactions.  At some point in code an exception is raised and the code bombs out.  It bombs out when clicking on a particular row record in a grid list.  However after the user sees the exception...they go back and try to click some other record..which should work..they again see the same exception which is not caused the second time around but still shows up since it showed up the first time.  This solves itself if user logs out ...logs back in and clicks on the second row ..which shouldnt have any problems.

would this be related to exceptions not getting cleared from the session when user goes back to the gridlist page..after they see the exception error page..?

Answer (score 1):

Generally after one operation in a transaction has failed, the transaction should be aborted and restarted. This allows you to go back to a "clean" state.